# Converting SAP nVARCHAR to a date

Tags: sql-server, date, hana, ssrs-2017

I am using SSRS 2017 to query a SAP hana database using an ODBC connection.

I return a date column `BUDAT` as `20190101`. I am trying to convert this to a date, but in the Sataset screen won't let me use the CONVERT or FORMAT command :

Attempt #1:

```
CONVERT(DATE, RIGHT(SAPABAP1.AFRU.BUDAT, 2) + SUBSTR(SAPABAP1.AFRU.BUDAT, 3, 2) + LEFT (SAPABAP1.AFRU.BUDAT, 4))
```

I get an error

> Invalid or missing expression

when I "enter" on the code I put in.

Attempt #2

```
format(SAPABAP1.AFRU.BUDAT, "dd/MM/yyyy")
```

SQL Server accepts the syntax, but when the query tried to run, I get the error

> General error;260 invalid column name;dd/MM/yyy:line1 col 1029 (as pos 1028)

I have spent the last few days off an on trying themes on this code but to no avail

I would like to see the output as `dd/MM/yyyy`.

Comment: You're using SAP Hana - not sql server. You need to use the appropriate sql features, functions, and syntax for SAP. If you are retrieving a date column, why do you attempt to convert it in the actual query? A better place to do that is where you display it.

Comment: Good morning thank you for the infromation, so in reality when I query SAP and pull the data over and its presented on the screen SQL converted the type of this field to NVARCHAR, I asumed that as I was in SQL I would then use SQL code to convert the data type in the field to what I wanted it to be ? do you have any idea on the sql/sap code to convert this field to a date ( note it works like a treat in Power BI just click on the row header and set it as a date and vloia its done ).

Comment: Replace double quotes in your format statement with single ones (apostrophes).

Comment: Hi Arvo, I tried that and also this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Once you consume DATS field in YYYYMMDD format, you will need to convert the String into the real Date value.

Assume `SAPABAP1.AFRU.BUDAT` is a valid string to be parsed:

For #1 (SSRS scenario), you need to use `Format(Cdate(SAPABAP1.AFRU.BUDAT),"yyyyMMdd").`

For #2 (SQL Server scenario), you need to use `CONVERT(datetime,SAPABAP1.AFRU.BUDAT,112)`, where "112" refers to yyyyMMdd. You can also omit 112 as yyyyMMdd is ISO format. Alternatively, you can do `CAST(SAPABAP1.AFRU.BUDAT as datetime)`.

Answer (score 0):

Good morning, thank you for taking the time to answer.

2-CONVERT(datetime,SAPABAP1.AFRU.BUDAT,112)-  when I enter the code in the sql side in the "column" where all the code goes, when I press enter to accept the code I get a microsoft visual studio error pop up window that says "function argument count error " and am unable to accept the code as you wrote.

2 -  Copy and pasting CAST(SAPABAP1.AFRU.BUDAT as datetime) in  - press enter I get the error invalid or missing expression.

What I have managed to do is get the date to resemble a date format using :

CONCAT(CONCAT(RIGHT (BUDAT, 2), SUBSTR(BUDAT, 5, 2)), LEFT (BUDAT, 4))

This gives the output from BUDAT 20190104 to 04012019 ( which is close to shat I need ).

Now 1-

Using the above code that works to get 01012019 I then used your code to convert this text to a date then format it ( note I changed the name of the field from Budat to postg_date for clarity ) :

=Format(Cdate(Fields!POSTG_DATE.Value),"ddMMyyyy")

The output in ssrs when its run gives me #ERROR in the output fieldI tried to include a screeen shot but I need 10 reutation points to do so :(

Currently we get the infromation I am looking at via an overnight download from SAP that goes in to a server that ises software called "universe" that is then squirted in to SQL that i Code against.
Do you think SQL 2017 cannot get convert the information directly form SAP in a format it can read